# rewrite folder name htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the folder name from `www.mysite.com/admin/page.php` to `www.mysite.com/administrator.version.1/page.php`

we should consider that admin folder exists but administrator.version.1 doesn't exist.it's just a name.

I search and find that query string can change,but I can't find any solution.

some of those solutions are

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^administrator.version.1/(.*) /admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /administrator.version.1/
RewriteRule ^administrator.version.1/(.*) /admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but they don't work.

my `htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^administrator.version.1/(.*) /admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

---

EDITED
I use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^administrator08.30.2015/(.*) /admin/$1 [L,R=301]
```

it works correctly but when I enter www.mysite.com/administrator08.30.2015/ ,it redirects me to www.mysite.com/admin/ 
and the browser show www.mysite.com/admin/ ,but I don't show admin ,I want to show administrator08.30.2015 in uri ,is it possible?

I remove R flag but it still redirects me.

Comment: If your redirecting everything from `admin` to `administration.version.1` then you can simply use `Redirect`.

Comment: no,I don't want to redirect ,because redirect means that I should have 2 same folder admin and administration.version.1.

Comment: @anubhava my all folders are in public_html, htaccess is in public_html folder too.

Comment: @anubhava yes .error is

Comment: Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /administrator.version.1/
RewriteRule ^administrator.version.1/(.*) /admin/$1 [L,R=301]

Comment: I clear second line                                                                                         RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /administrator.version.1/                       ,but it dosen't help

Comment: I do it ,and it generates 500 error

Comment: Add a `RewriteRule ^foo$ /admin/ [L,R]` rule and enter `www.mysite.com/foo` in browser to see what it does.

Comment: @anubhava what's the problem? does it work for you?

Comment: @anubhava when I use this site ( http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ ) to test my htaccess,the output url can't change. could you see this site,please?

Comment: That site is useless for rule testing. Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled in your Apache config?

Comment: Make sure your htaccess file is being processed. You need to make sure `AllowOverride` is on in your server config.

Comment: @JonLin how can I be sure about AllowOverride ?

Comment: # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    AllowOverride all

Comment: I remove # from begining of AllowOverride all

Answer (score 0):

Mahmood Akbarian, one of my best friend, tell me a solution, and it is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^administrator.v1/(.*) admin/$1
```